# Dynamic table with data from infobox data on other pages in a MediaWiki

Tags: mysql, mediawiki, dynamic-pages, semantic-mediawiki

We're using ***mediawiki*** at our office and we needed to create infoboxes to store informations about softwares that we manage.

We created an ***infobox*** for softwares, we have now 40 infoboxes in 40 softwares pages.
Each software page is in the ***software*** category, that let us getting an index of all softwares from the menu.

But we would need also a table that shows a summary of many of the informations presented in the infoboxes.

Is there a way to achieve that in mediawiki? i know we can make a table to store all that informations but it would be a bit redundant, that's why we're dreaming about a dynamic table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install [Semantic Mediawiki](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/).

Then use parser function #ask for [inline queries](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aInline_queries) ... <--- more details how to, at this link.

See a SMW demo article at [Berlin](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Demo%3aBerlin) or [Paris](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Demo%3aParis) and how the info from these is then included in a [Table of Cities](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Category%3aCity) on another page.

Comment: Ok after searching a bit, i discovered the features of that extension : it seems great, thanks!